# Why is it said that photon-wavelengths have increased by a factor of 1000 since our universe became transparent to light?

Tags: cosmology, photons, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background

After reading several explanations for the so-called "Hubble-radius", and still being confused, (as I reckon are some of the folks who tried to answer THAT question !!), I have a related question, which I hope might help clarify this issue. It's said that the average wavelength of photons at the time when our universe became transparent to light, [i.e., at approx. 300,000 years after the Big Bang started], was about 1000 times less than what it is now, and that each photon carried about 1000 times as much energy. These are, of course, the photons which constitute the so-called "cosmic microwave backround" [CMB] radiation. If our universe has been expanding at approx. the same rate since year-300,000 it seems like the factor would be more like (13 billion) / (300 thousand), which is much larger than 1000. Am I missing something important here?

Comment: What you are missing is that the expansion rate has not been constant.  Very soon after the BB there was a period called inflation that caused expansion at an unbelievably high rate.  You should google the CMB where you will see a wine bottle shaped graph that shows how we think the expansion rate varied from the earliest moments after the BB to the present.

Comment: Here is a link to the graph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe

Comment: @LewisMiller: about your 1st comment , inflation preceded the CMB emission time.

Comment: not (13 billion) / (300 thousand) but ( 13 billion - 300 thousand) by some factor, called Hubble constant ( product some units' factor )

Comment: HMMMM:  my first impulse was to regard "inflation" as not applicable here, as it occurred before our universe became transparent to light ... I see that one commenter (above) + one answerer (below) seem to agree ... in fact, I'm skeptical of the whole concept of "inflation" !!

Comment: Sure. But the inflation model can be matched to what is observed, and since fields in that early epoch must have been pretty extraordinary its not to be discounted.

Comment: @BobBee  O --- you're right !!   I like the simpler models, and detest some of the "higher math" which one needs for inflation-models ... however, as you say, they cannot be discounted

Comment: You need "higher math" for most of physics and cosmology, unfortunately (so to speak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the lookback time to redshift relation in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift

You can ignore inflation if you get redshifts, temperatures and universe size (radius, scale) ratios between now and times in the past after inflation. For recombination the relations of 1+z to the scale ratios and temperature ratios are linear and direct . So for T(then)/Tnow) = 3000K/3K = 1000 you get z about 1000, or more exactly closer to 1100.

Similarly, the scale ratio of 1000 would give you the size of the universe at recombination of about 13.8 million light years (again, you can use exact numbers for better accuracy).

But the lookback time is not linear. That Wikipedia article has the equation. The Dodelson book derives it exactly and dos more calculations, and it's not that hard. There is also an online calculator, but it won't teach you anything. The dependence is that lookback time is proportional to (1+z)^(-3/2).

Comment: Yes:  1000^(3/2) = 3,1600,  which is exactly the ratio of  13 billion to 410 thousand, which is close-enough to 300 thousand for me !!

Comment: Yes, and keep in mind it's closer to 1100

Comment: Yes!! that works